# Mac Error Code -50

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac

been tinkering with an old Mac Mini I received (2010.... I guess it’s not *that* old but still... thought would be a nice idea to just dump Linux on it; not a knock on Mac since I do have a mbp and it is aging tech now) and been having troubles with it. When I first got it, the following happened (also on Mac OS High Sierra):

1. I would have trouble creating/deleting files on it; it would report the -50 error code and say “Operation can’t be completed.”
2. When rebooting, it would just jump to white screen and try internet recovery by itself.

   3. When I attempted to do first aid on the drive, it shoots back “Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting”.

So after seeing #3, I decided to reformat the drive and just reinstall Mac OS Sierra. However, after a couple of days, problems 1-3 still happen and it’s getting a bit frustrating not being able to find a solution on the internet. Is it safe to say the drive (a seagate rpm drive apparently) is toast? I don’t mind putting a new drive in but wanted to get other people’s opinions first.

Comment: It does sound like your drive is gone, you can try and diagnose it via bootable tool provided by the manufacturer. https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/seatools/

Comment: @EnisP.Aginić hm looks like that tool is windows only? Nevertheless just gonna replace the drive / back up since it looks like it might just not boot one day! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should be able to use Legacy Tools ISO image for DOS, just burn ISO image to a CD and hold Option while tuning your computer on to boot from it.